# R: mute output of Sys.setlocale()

Tags: r, logging, output, mute

I run a script `Rscript script.R > logfile.of.script.txt`

in the script i set

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

which returns

```
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

however this text persists in the log files which i don't want to have. How can I have     `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")` run quietly without any output to the logfile. `Sys.setlocale()` does not see, to have a quiet switch to suppress output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assign it or wrap in `invisible(.)`:

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United States.1252")
# [1] "English_United States.1252"
invisible(Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United States.1252"))
ign <- Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English_United States.1252")
```

While this function does have side-effect, it also returns the new value. Since it is doing partial-matching to find the best, the return value is not always the same as the argument provided. For instance,

```r
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
# [1] "English_United States.1252"
```

shows what I wanted and what I got ... so the most-paranoid approach might be to make sure you got what you requested (in case the partial-matching is over-eager). I've never been in a situation where that level of paranoia was required, but then again I'm fortunate that all of my work is in a single language (my primary language) with no multi-lingual users.

Comment: Thank you very much. However I don't understand when it could go wrong. Is it possible to provide an example where invisible could go wrong?

Comment: I don't work enough with locale-based differences to know when it can go wrong. The defensive-programmer in me sees that I request one locale (`"English"`) but another is actually assigned (`"English_United States.1252"`), which to me suggests two things: (1) the convenience of not having to know anything about locale code-pages (1252); and (2) perhaps I know what I want, and R (or the underlying OS libraries) don't understand that one, so it chooses the next-best-fit, which may not be good enough. I don't *know* that there could be a problem, I'm just finding unadvertised behavior.

Comment: Plus `?Sys.setlocale` is seemingly contradictory (*'"LC_TIME"' may affect the behaviour of 'as.POSIXlt' and 'strptime' and functions which use them (but not 'date'.)"*, which is inconsistent with what I demonstrated above), and it is likely OS-specific (*For Windows, Microsoft moves its documentation frequently so a Web search is the best way to find current information*). But nowhere do I see mention of "partial match".

Comment: Bottom line: I don't work enough in locale to have a concrete example of when a partial-match would actually present a broken situation. All I'm saying is that the under-documented and inconsistent behavior (from its docs) of `Sys.setlocale` sets off a few minor alarms in my head. It is likely safe-enough to use `invisible(Sys.setlocale(..))` and move on.